# Composition of measurable functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Consider a locally bounded function $f: X \times W \rightarrow X$, where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, such that

for all $x \in X$ the function $w \mapsto f(x,w)$ is (Borel) measurable;

Consider a locally bounded, (Borel) measurable, function $g: W \rightarrow X$.

Say if the function

$$ (w,v) \mapsto f( g(w), v ) $$

is (Borel) measurable as well.

Notes: this question differs from both [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126606/is-a-composition-of-lebesgue-measurable-functions-measurable) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72913/are-measurable-functions-closed-under-addition-and-multiplication-but-not-compo) post.

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch3.pdf): if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable and $g: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable then $f \circ g$ is Borel measurable as well. Can we generalize that?

Comment: Also in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the composition of two Borel mappings is a Borel mapping as well [Bogachev - Measure Theory, pag. 146].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to prove does not hold. Let $V$ be the [Vitali Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) which is not measurable in $B(\mathcal{R})$. Let $f: R^{2} \mapsto R$, such that:

$$ f(x,y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{$x \in V$};\\
        0 & \mbox{$x \notin V$}.\end{array} \right. $$

Note that $f$ is locally bounded and for any $x \in R$, $y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is Borel measurable, since it is constant. Let $g$ be the identity function. Observe that $f(g(x),y) = f(x,y)$ which is not measurable in $(R^{2},B(\mathcal{R}^{2}))$.

Comment: Why $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Also, if $g$ is from $W$ to $X$ how can it be the identity?

Comment: f is not measurable... but you didn't say it had to be.  Consider $W = X$, for this example.

Comment: I mean why for all $x \in X$ we have $w \mapsto f(x,w)$ measurable?

Comment: If $x \in A$, $w \mapsto f(x,w) = 1$ which is measurable. If $x \notin A$, $w \mapsto f(x,w) = 0$, which is measurable.

Comment: So in your example, $n=1$. Why is this example not contradicting [this](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch3.pdf) (after Definition 3.3)?

Comment: I see no contradiction. Can you write where you think the contradiction is?

Comment: For instance, what do you mean by $A \in X$ is not measurable? Any measurable/non-measurable set should be in $W$, not in $X$. No measures are defined for $X$.

Comment: I will edit the answer to make it more explicit.